# US open scoring system

Tags: tennis, atp, wta

How does the scoring system in US open differ from other majors and normal ATP/WTA turnaments?

My understading is this: In ATP they go best of five sets like French Open etc. but have a tie break after 6-6 in each sets like any other non-major tournament. Except for qualification where they play like any other ATP tournament.

In WTA they play just like any other WTA tournament.

Correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the non-major tournaments (so all tournaments except the Australian Open, French Open, Wimbledon and US Open) - both the ATP and WTA plays best of 3 sets. During the majors, the men play best of 5 sets and the women still play best of 3 sets. In the 4 majors, the 5th set (for men, 3rd set for women) must be won by a margin of 2 games, rather than a tie break - except for the US Open. The US Open plays a tie break at the end of the 5th set (or 3rd set for women) instead of a margin of 2 games. That is the difference.